# Resolution Scaling on 4k Laptop

Tags: gnome, resolution, monitor, 15.04, gsettings

I've tried following directions at

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI

and

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/linux-hidpi-support-for-gnome-kde-xfce-cinnamon-and-firefox/

to make my Ubuntu desktop on my latest 4k desktop more readable and in turn usable.

but when doing

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2
```

on my terminal I get a temporary magnification flash followed by a reset to normal (unusuable) rendering resolution.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04.

What to do?

Update: According to https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTYzMTM there should be "UI Scale factor" but I can't find it in the Ubuntu system settings. Where is it? Is it the same as the gsettings call mentioned above?

Comment: I use two settings to configure ubuntu for hidpi: 

system settings -> displays -> scale for menu and title bars, 
system settings -> appearance -> launcher icon size.

Does any of them do what you want?

Besides that, most configuration is on a per-application basis.